# Intuition about the lack of a quadratic term in geometric expansions

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(\Sigma,g)$ be a Riemannian 2-manifold and let $p\in\Sigma$. It turns out that the circumference $C(r)$ of a geodesic circle $S_r(p)$ of radius $r$ around $p$ satisfies
$$
C(r)=2\pi r-\frac{\pi}{3}Kr^3+O(r^4),
$$
where $K$ denotes the Gaussian curvature of $\Sigma$ in $p$. On the other hand, if $\gamma$ is a smooth arc length parametrized curve in $\Sigma$ with $\gamma(0)=p$, then the geodesic distance from $p$ to $\gamma(t)$ satisfies
$$
d(p,\gamma(t))=t-\frac{k_g^2}{24}t^3+O(t^4),
$$
where $k_g$ denotes the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$ in $p$. Now here's the question. Can somebody give me an intuitive reason why there are no quadratic terms in these expansions? At least for the second expansion I have a vague idea why this is plausible but maybe there is a neat explanation for this. Of course, the proofs of the statements "explain" somehow, that/why there are no quadratic terms but I'm really looking for some heuristics/an intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Consider $$  f(0)=f'(0)=0,\ f(t)=f(-t),\ f'(t)>0\ (t>0)$$

With $t=0$, we rotate $f$. Then $$ r(s):={\rm length}\ \{ (t,f(t))|
0\leq t\leq s \} =\int_0^s \sqrt{ 1+(f')^2 },\ r'(0)=1 $$

If $f'(t)=c_1t+c_2t^2+\cdots$ (cf. Taylor series), $$r(s)=\int_0^s
(1+c_3t^2 + c_4t^3 +\cdots )\ dt =s+c_5s^3 +\cdots $$

(2) That is in the revolution surface (i.e., fixed point is
corresponded to $t=0$), length of geodesic sphere of radius $r$ is
$$ l(r)/(2\pi )=s= r - c_6 r^3 + \cdots
$$

(3) Consider two spheres $S^2(r),\ S^2(R),\ r< R $ If $M$ is a
surface and if curvature $K$ at $p\in M$ has $K(p)>0$, then for
given $\epsilon >0$, we have $\delta$ s.t. on $B_\delta (p)$,
$$ |K-K(p) | <\epsilon
$$

So we have $$ \frac{1}{R^2} < K < \frac{1}{r^2} $$

That is three surfaces are tangent at fixed point and on
$\delta$-balls except fixed point do not intersect. So intuitively
$$ l_{S^2(r)} (t) < l_M (t) < l_{S^2(R)} (t) $$

That is $M$ does not have quadratic term

Comment: Thank you for your answer! A few comments: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand the purpose of (1) and (2): If you look at a surface of revolution you roughly obtain
$$r(s)=\sqrt{1+f'(0)^2}s+\frac{f'(0)f''(0)}{2\sqrt{1+f'(0)^2}}s^2+O(s^3).$$
If $f'(0)=0$, the quadratic term vanishes , ok, but I don't know how this gives an intuitive reason for the lack of the quadratic term. Am I getting (3) correctly: You take 2 comparison-spheres at $p$ and get $$2\pi r\sin t\leqslant \ell_M(t)\leqslant 2\pi R\sin t$$ right? How does it exclude the appearance of a quadratic term?

Comment: You are right. $r(s)= c_1s+c_2s^2+\cdots $ Here by condition of $f$, $c_2=0$ I want to show that in sphere case $C(r)$ does not contain quaratic term. More generally in (1), (2) this holds for all revolution surface

Comment: $sin\ (t)$ does not contains a quadratic term. If $l_M(t)$ has the quadratic term, $2\pi r- Cr^3 +\cdots \geq 2\pi r+C_2 r^2 +\cdots,\ C_2>0$ It is impossible

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get the last part. Say for example if $R=2, r=1$, then the (possible) function $\ell_M(t)=3\pi t+\frac{1}{2}t^2-t^3$ satisfies the chain of inequalities
$$
2\pi \sin t\leqslant 3\pi t+\frac{1}{2}t^2-t^3\leqslant 4\pi\sin t
$$
on $[0,\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$ (actually one can take $\delta=1$).

Comment: No In $S^2(k)$, length of geodesic sphere of radius $r$ is $2\pi k \sin\ \frac{r}{k} =2\pi r -C r^3 +\cdots $

Comment: Yes, I forgot the scaling. This answers the first part of the question. Do you have any idea regarding the second?